# I want to take user input and put it into an array of strings c++

Tags: c++

I want to take in user input and put what they type into an array of strings. I want it to read each character and separate each word by white space. I am sure this is coded badly, although I did try to do it decent. I am getting a segmentation fault error and was wondering how I could go about doing this without getting the error. Here is the code I have.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void stuff(char command[][5])
{ 
    int b, i = 0;
    char ch;
    cin.get(ch);

    while (ch != '\n')
    {
        command[i][b] = ch;
        i++;
        cin.get(ch);
        if(isspace(ch))
        {
            cin.get(ch);
            b++;

        }

    }
    for(int n = 0; n<i; n++)
    {
        for(int m = 0; m<b; m++)
            {
            cout << command[n][m];
            }
    }

}

int main()
{
    char cha[25][5];
    char ch;
    cin.get(ch);
    while (ch != 'q')
    {
        stuff(cha);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not using a `std::vector<std::string> >` and apply `cin` to the strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`b` is not initialised so will have a random value when first used as the index. Initialise `b` and ensure array indexes do not go beyond the bounds of the array.

Alternatively, use a [`std::vector<std::string>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and `operator>>()` and forget about array indexes:

```
std::string word;
std::vector<std::string> words;
while (cin >> word && word != "q") words.push_back(word);
```

Comment: Thanks! Whenever I use a space I get weird characters in the array. Do you know what would fix that also?